# Introducing increment variable in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, foreach

In my view I want to introduce a variable of type `int` which will be used in foreach loop. The main idea behind is I want to use it as serial number for the rows of table.

This is what I have now

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    int sno = 1;
}
@foreach (var object in Model.object)
{
   <tr>
      <td>sno++</td>//@sno++ and {@sno++;} didn't work either
      <td>some stuffs</td>
   </tr>

}
```

Right now it just shows `sno++` in view

How can I make this work?

Comment: have you tried: `@{sno++;}` and then `<td>@sno</td>` ? In separate lines of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping with parentheses:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    int sno = 1;
}
@foreach (var object in Model.object)
{
   <tr>
      <td>@(sno++)</td>
      <td>some stuffs</td>
   </tr>
}
```

This is required because explicit code expressions will render as text, so to do the actual calculation, it will need to be wrapped with parentheses

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>@sno</td>
@{sno++;}
```